# How to exclude dev dependancies from black duck scans for an android project while running scans in AzureDevOps pipelines with synopsis detect8 task?

Tags: android, gradle, blackduck, synopsis-detect

I have an Android project and I am running BlackDuck scan in the AzureDevOps pipeline using the following configuration

```
- task: SynopsysDetectTask@8
  displayName: 'Run Synopsys Detect for your build '
  inputs:
    BlackDuckService: '$(BlackDuckService)'
    DetectArguments: |
      --detect.project.name=$(Build.Repository.Name)
      --detect.project.version.name=v1
      --detect.gradle.excluded.configurations=test...{some long list of test libs}
```

But the results I am getting have all the test dependencies that were supposed to be excluded.

I followed this link for the exclusion options:

1. https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/How-can-I-exclude-test-libraries-in-a-Gradle-file-in-Black-Duck-Detect-scans
2. https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Exclude-Gradle-configurations-from-Detect-scans

Any help is appreciated to fix this problem.